# Code snippet with special sign = ' " ' in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I have written following snippet:

```
"Insert IMG": {
    "prefix": "iimg",
    "body": [
        "<img src='./img/$1/$2'><br><br>",
    ],
    "description": "Insert image to MD file"
}
```

but in the body I want to have:

```
"<img src="./img/$1/$2"><br><br>",
```

How to achieve it? I was trying with hex code but does not work ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want double quotes, just escape them:

```
    "<img src=\"./img/$1/$2\"><br><br>",
```